# Salesforce :Group data in Visualforce page

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I want to create a timesheet page to group all the timesheets together(i.e. when timesheet are added for a week split between two projects then two timesheet records are created).

So, I want to group timesheets for a week based on start date and then also show the result grouped according to resources

Like
WEEK ENDING DATE - 3RD JAN 2012 ; Resource Name - abc

- project name -test , total hrs 16
- project name - test2 , total hrs 20

All this details is available on timesheet record.

Below is my controller:

```
public class TimesheetHeader {

    public Map<Date,Set<pse__Timecard_Header__c>> getTimecardMap(){
    return timecardMap;
    }

   public Map<Date,Set<pse__Timecard_Header__c>> timecardMap = new Map<Date,Set<pse__Timecard_Header__c>>();
   Set<pse__Timecard_Header__c> timecardSet = new Set<pse__Timecard_Header__c>(); 

   Date tcdate;

    public TimesheetHeader(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {

     List<pse__Timecard_Header__c> timecardheader = [Select f.Id,f.Name,f.pse__Start_Date__c,f.pse__End_Date__c,f.pse__Project__r.Name,f.pse__Status__c,f.pse__Total_Hours__c From pse__Timecard_Header__c f ]; 

         for(pse__Timecard_Header__c tc :timecardheader ){
          tcdate = tc.pse__End_Date__c;
          System.debug('tcdate---->'+tcdate);

           if(timecardMap.containsKey(tcdate)){
          Set<pse__Timecard_Header__c> temp = new Set<pse__Timecard_Header__c>();
          temp = timecardMap.get(tcdate);
          temp.add(tc);
          timecardMap.put(tcdate,temp);
          temp.clear();
          }
         else{
         timecardSet.add(tc);
         timecardMap.put(tcdate,timecardSet);

        }       
    }
    System.debug('timecardMap------>'+timecardMap.keySet());
   } 
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data table with fake values to show how you'd want the data to be presented? Are you familiar with "subqueries"? Something like `SELECT Name, (SELECT Email FROM Contacts) FROM Account`. It seems you could query in a way similar to `SELECT Name, (SELECT Id FROM pse__Timecard_Headers__r) FROM pse__Project__c` (I'm just guessing at the object and field names!)

Comment: All the detail is available on timesheets. I just want to group data .I have added the example in my question.

Answer (score 0):

First fine-tune your query in the query editor. You probably should read about aggregate functions like SUM(), MAX() etc. and the GROUP BY clause.

It's hard for me to figure out all your data (for example what's the "resource"? Owner of the Timesheet_Header record?) but this fairly similar query should give you some ideas:

```
SELECT CloseDate, Account.Name, SUM(Amount) amount
FROM Opportunity
GROUP BY CloseDate, Account.Name
```

Results from my developer edition:

[image]

You'll need WHERE clause to limit it to same week but still - it's something?
If the days don't match exactly (seems unlikely in your scenario) you could use some of [the date functions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm).

```
SELECT CALENDAR_YEAR(CloseDate) cy, CALENDAR_MONTH(CloseDate) cm, WEEK_IN_MONTH(CloseDate) cw, SUM(Amount) amount
FROM Opportunity
GROUP BY CALENDAR_YEAR(CloseDate), CALENDAR_MONTH(CloseDate), WEEK_IN_MONTH(CloseDate)
```

[image]

One way or another - you should end up with query that shows what you want.

The next step is to show the data in Visualforce. These "aggregate queries" return a weird thing called AggregateResult. It'll be your job to get the columns out of it and map them to some helper class variables. This class should have fields marked as `public get;` at least.

I'm too lazy to type it all ;) Check out my answer at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21978/display-the-related-aggregated-value-on-a-vf-page or just Google a bit about how to handle aggregate query results.

---

If you don't want aggregate queries it's still doable.

Think what would be your unique keys. I'd say that a combination of Week (ok, Date field probably) and the resource (whatever it is). Maybe even only the resource since you wish to show data for same week.

And values? `List<something>` where something holds the project name and total hours. I'd still make the "something" a helper wrapper class consisting of string (project name), id (to construct a link) and numeric value (total hours).

Once you have such design start building a `Map<string, List<wrapper>>` where the string is either resource or resource+week.